# Checking user keypresses creates a warning

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I am attempting to keep user inputs into our application as clean as possible. One way I am attempting to do this is not allowing incorrect data type in fields (not allowing alpha characters when expecting numeric values)

I found and implemented the following code:

```
Private Sub txtSocial_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtSocial.KeyPress
    Dim UserKeyPress As Char = e.KeyChar
    Dim isKey As Boolean = e.KeyChar.IsDigit(UserKeyPress)
    Dim isCont As Boolean = e.KeyChar.IsControl(UserKeyPress)
    If Not isKey And Not isCont Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If
```

The code works as desired however Visual Studio throws this warning:

> Access of shared member, constant
>   member, enum member or nested type
>   through an instance; qualifying
>   expression will not be evaluated.

I am not opposed to warnings, but I would like to know if there is whether I ignore the warning and move on, or is there a better way to accomplish my goals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `e.KeyChar.IsDigit`, use `Char.IsDigit`. Same thing for `IsControl`. When accessing a static (shared) method like IsDigit, you can access it directly through the class instead of a specific instance: the instance (`e.KeyChar` in this case) would be ignored anyway, and this is what the warning is about.

Comment: Awesome no more warnings and I still have the same functionality.